# What's current state of Mono 2.8 development?

Tags: .net, mono

Where can I look at what features planned for Mono 2.8 release are already implemented in Mono SVN?

Comment: check this link [Release Notes Mono 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also have a look at :

1) http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap#Upcoming_Releases

2) http://www.mono-project.com/Plans

3) http://www.mono-project.com/MoonlightRoadmap#Upcoming_Releases